# How to override remove method of repeat element and perform both operations of removing and adding some logic in ngx formly angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-formly, ngx-formly

I'm using a repeat field in which there is a remove button that works fine normally, but my requirement is to perform some logic while removing the element in which I call a customize function onRemove instead of remove(i), could anyone help me to achieve this, following is the stackblitz demo : [click here stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-formly-repeat-i91pwz?file=app/repeat-section.type.ts), below find an explanation which I tried and doesn't work out.

Explanation with Screenshot:

**Step 1.** Click on the remove button, function remove(i) is called.
[image]

**Step 2.** Instead of remove, I need to call a function that will perform some logic before removing it, I tried doing it I was able to call the function but was not able to remove the element.

Code snippet of which I tried using for removing element in formlytype component:

*In repeat-section.type.ts*:

```
<button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" (click)="OnRemove(i)">Remove</button>

export class RepeatTypeComponent extends FieldArrayType {
constructor(builder: FormlyFormBuilder) {
super(builder);
}
 onRemove() {
  console.log('---->remove');
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
onRemove(i: number) {

// your logic

// calls the extended FieldArrayType remove() method to delete the row from the model and 
// the formly FormlyFieldConfig's for that row from your repeat type fieldGroup
super.remove(i);   
}
```